# Splines with a knot that varies by factor level

Tags: splines, segmented-regression

I have data that reaches a peak then declines. While I might do this as segmented or spline regression, there is a complication. The position of the knot appears to differ depending on the level of a factor in the data. If the factor is "A", then the peak appears to exist at position 5, but if the factor is "B", the peak appears to be at position 4. Can I tell if this apparent difference is real? Can I test different estimated peak positions?

Comment: Define "different peak positions". A "position" is, of course, a tuple $(x_{max}, y_{max})$ for which $y_{max}$ attains its in-sample maximum over a range of $x$. Is your alternate hypothesis that $(x_{1, max}, y_{1, max}) \ne (x_{2, max}, y_{2, max}) $? or is it that just $x_{1,max} \ne x_{1,max}$ or is it that $y_{1, max} \ne y_{2, max}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can look at the interaction of the spline and the factor. In R, there is at least one package devoted just to this sort of analysis `interactionRCS` (not surprisingly, from the name, it uses restricted cubic splines.  You can also do this in SAS, I forget the exact syntax and I no longer license SAS, but it is possible.

Comment: A problem with this answer is that a test of the difference in the spline parameters (what you suggest) is not necessarily a test of the difference of the maximum of a curve over a domain (what the OP has asked for) especially not with cubic splines.